# Parse and display JSON data in angular2

Tags: javascript

Can someone give some example how to parse below object?
All I need is one field.

I see lot of example with simple objects, not for complex.

> {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Nashville","short_name":"Nashville","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Davidson County","short_name":"Davidson County","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Tennessee","short_name":"TN","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Nashville, TN, USA","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":36.4054959,"lng":-86.5155879},"southwest":{"lat":35.9677851,"lng":-87.054903}},"location":{"lat":36.1626638,"lng":-86.7816016},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":36.4054959,"lng":-86.5155879},"southwest":{"lat":35.9677851,"lng":-87.054903}}},"place_id":"ChIJPZDrEzLsZIgRoNrpodC5P30","types":["locality","political"]}],"status":"OK"}

Comment: This is not "parsing", which is something different. Don't use that word. It is "accessing". It has nothing to do with Angular. It is plain old JavaScript. Your title says "parse and display"; your question mentions "parsing", but not "display". Is your problem that you want to "parse" it, or "display" it? Which field do you want? What problems are you having accessing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

Which field do you want ? Because your Object seems already ok.
By example :

```
var test = {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Nashville","short_name":"Nashville","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Davidson County","short_name":"Davidson County","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Tennessee","short_name":"TN","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Nashville, TN, USA","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":36.4054959,"lng":-86.5155879},"southwest":{"lat":35.9677851,"lng":-87.054903}},"location":{"lat":36.1626638,"lng":-86.7816016},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":36.4054959,"lng":-86.5155879},"southwest":{"lat":35.9677851,"lng":-87.054903}}},"place_id":"ChIJPZDrEzLsZIgRoNrpodC5P30","types":["locality","political"]}],"status":"OK"};
test.results[0].place_id; // will give you "ChIJPZDrEzLsZIgRoNrpodC5P30"
```

If you want `"southwest":{"lat":35.9677851,"lng":-87.054903}`, you can use :

```
var southwestValues = test.results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest;
var lat = southwestValues.lat; // gives you 35.9677851
var long = southwestValues.lng; // gives you -87.054903
```

Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16521195)

Comment: say Lat and Lng value of southwest

Comment: "southwest":{"lat":35.9677851,"lng":-87.054903}

Comment: @David, how is it not an answer ? I give an example to access to one of the fields, which is, if I'm not wrong, what asked !